# How to use a custom event in C#

Tags: c#, events, animation, dll

I have a library for some great transitions on windows forms, and it has a feature to fire off an event when the transition is done, but I have no idea how to utilize it.

http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/wiki/CodingWithTransitions#Using_the_TransitionCompletedEvent

There is the library

This is the event i need to deal with

TransitionCompletedEvent

If anyone could help me understand how to use this event that would be great!

Answer (score 3):

You register a method to handle the event.

```
transition.TransitionCompletedEvent += theHandlerFunction;
```

The handler function should have the following signature:

```
private void theHandlerFunction(object sender, Args args)
```